# Over-enthusiastic Intellisense in VS2010 - can I tweak it?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Since I have upgraded from VS2008 to VS2010, I've been having an increasingly infuriating battle with the Intellisense.

For example, when specifying CSS styles, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start an new line, Intellisense (appropriately) lists available Styles to me. And if I select `color` and then type ':', it presents a list of color presets - often helpful. However, if I type in a space (I like them for readability) or if I type '#' to enter RGB values, it selected the default Intellisense selection, in this case `inherits`.

Another example is in an ASP.NET page - say I am concatenating strings, I type `myString =`, I get an Intellisense pop-up. If I type <kbd>space</kbd> or '"' (to enter a literal) or '.' (so select a property or method within a `WITH` block), the Intellisense selects the first entry in the list.

I can dismiss the Intellisense pop-ups with <kbd>escape</kbd> but it makes it incredibly slow to code.

This behaviour is different to my VS2008 set-up. I can't seem to find any way to configure Intellisense to behave differently... I really only want it to select and Intellisense entry when I type  or ... at least, certainly not when I type '"' or ' ' or '.'!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved:

Being the idiot that I am, I hadn't properly checked for extensions; when I did, I found I had the [Intellisense Presenter extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ca201b20-8100-4f9a-a653-a20ae308e82e) installed, and digging further it appear that my experience is not unique. It's a promising extension, but is currently unusable in this state.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't normal.  Start with Tools + Import and Export, select Reset all Settings.  Next step is to run devenv.exe with the /safemode command line argument so it runs with all add-ins disabled.

Comment: I tried that, but apart from changing all my preferences, it had no effect.